# Can't copy/paste uneditable question

Tags: support

I'd like to copy code that wasn't properly formatted as code from a question. I can't edit the question to properly format it though, because it has already been edited and the edition is pending review (see image)

[image]

The question has probably been edited to format text properly, but I can't see the edited version nor the plaintext question, either of which would allow me to copy it properly.

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can construct the revision URL for the post on your own and then point your browser to that. This is the recipe:

- Start with the URL of a question: `https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/352326/blah`,
- replace `questions` with `posts`
- replace `blah` with `revisions`

> [`https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/352326/revisions`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/352326/revisions)

When your browser loads that URL this will be the result:

> [image]

where you then click to view the source of a particular revision. That will give you the exact markdown of that revision.

> [image]

If you find fiddling with an URL cumbersome you can try some of the userscripts that try to solve that issue as well like [SE Modifications](https://stackapps.com/questions/2138/se-modifications-username-autocomplete-in-comments-inline-revision-source-a) and [Add Timeline and Revisions links](https://stackapps.com/questions/2047/add-timeline-and-revisions-links). I didn't test or use these scripts.